# Verify Google Access Token in Spring Boot Microservices System

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-oauth, microservices, access-token

so I am in a bit of situation, I have a microservice system that contains an api gateway, and a user microservice, i initially had an open custom login endpoint in my user microservice that returns a jwt and an user object (id, email and roles), the request passes my api gateway and since its an open endpoint, it lets it go through and gets the jwt and sets the jwt in the headers against closed endpoints. Now i am implementing a google sign in mechanism, from postman, i am able to get an access token, but then i need to pass the token to the api gateway, the token would be sent to an open separate endpoint in the user microservice to validate the access token and get the user info eg name and email. Unfortunately when using the code from the documentation, it returns a Precondition error like this: `com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:131)`
This is the method for validating the access token:

```
public UserDto validateOAuth2Token(String token) {
        System.out.println("Comes to user controller with token"+ token);
        NetHttpTransport httpTransport = null;
        try {
            httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            GsonFactory jsonFactory = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
            GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory)
                    .setAudience(Collections.singletonList("MY_CLIENT_ID"))
                    .build();
            GoogleIdToken idToken = verifier.verify(token);
            if (idToken != null) {
                GoogleIdToken.Payload payload = idToken.getPayload();
                String email = payload.getEmail();
                return userDtoMapper.apply(customOAuth2UserService.upsertUser(email));
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid ID token.");
                throw new GeneralSecurityException("Invalid ID token.");
            }
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

I have also added my AuthFilter class of my api gateway:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class AuthFilter extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<AuthFilter.Config> {
    private final WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;
    public AuthFilter(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
        super(Config.class);
        this.webClientBuilder = webClientBuilder;
    }
    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        return (exchange, chain) -> {
            try {
                if (!exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().containsKey(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)) {
                    throw new GatewayException("Missing authorization information");
                }
                String authHeader = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
                String[] parts = authHeader.split(" ");
                if (parts.length != 2 || !"Bearer".equals(parts[0])) {
                    throw new GatewayException("Incorrect authorization structure");
                }
                String token = parts[1];
                String customValidationUri = "http://gateway-service/api/uu/v1/users/token/validate?token=" + token;
                String socialValidationUri = "http://user-service/api/uu/v1/users/oauth2/validate?token=" + token;
                Mono<UserDto> validationRequest;
                log.info(token);
                if (isSocialLogin(token)) {
                    validationRequest = webClientBuilder.build()
                            .post()
                            .uri(socialValidationUri)
                            .retrieve()
                            .bodyToMono(UserDto.class);
                } else {
                    validationRequest = webClientBuilder.build()
                            .post()
                            .uri(customValidationUri)
                            .retrieve()
                            .bodyToMono(UserDto.class);
                }
                return validationRequest.flatMap(user -> {
                    exchange.getRequest()
                            .mutate()
                            .header("x-id", String.valueOf(user.getId()))
                            .header("x-email", String.valueOf(user.getEmail()))
                            .header("x-roles", user.getRoles().toString())
                            .build();
                    return chain.filter(exchange);
                });
            } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
                return handleException(ex, exchange);
            }
        };
    }

    private boolean isSocialLogin(String token){
        if (token.startsWith("ya29")) {
            System.out.println("This is a google login");
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("This is not a google login");
            return false;
        }
    }
    private Mono<Void> handleException(Exception ex, ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        log.error("Error validating authentication header", ex);
        List<String> details = new ArrayList<>();
        details.add(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse(new Date(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(),
                HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.name(), details, exchange.getRequest().getURI().toString());
        ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
        byte[] bytes = SerializationUtils.serialize(error);
        DataBuffer buffer = exchange.getResponse().bufferFactory().wrap(bytes);
        response.writeWith(Mono.just(buffer));
        response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        return response.setComplete();
    }
    public static class Config {
    }
}
```

I need the email of the signed in user to save in my database if the user does not exist already, Please help me out to solve this issue if you can, and i am open to advice, suggestions, opinions towards a better approach, industry standards, best practices etc.